# WPF binding List<Dictionary<string,string>> to a ListBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

```
var list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>{
                new Dictionary<string,string>{
                    {"id","1"},
                    {"name","foo"},
                }, 
                new Dictionary<string,string>{
                    {"id","2"},
                    {"name","bar"},
                }
            };
```

I want to bind this list to a listbox. It's quite simple:

```
listBox.ItemsSource=list;
```

but the problem is: I can't control what is displayed in the listbox. What I want is to display is dict["name"]. I tried:

```
listbox.DisplayMemberPath="name"
```

Sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to display a property called `name` on the dictionary, which doesn't exist. To access an indexer use the following syntax:

```
listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "[name]";
```

Also, you should be probably setting things like this directly in XAML, not in code-behind.

Comment: Wow, you answered my question one minute before I figured it out myself. And apparently your solution is simpler. thank you!

Comment: Actually, I answered it about one minute after you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,35,0,77" Width="88" Name="mainListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=[name]}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

pay attention to `<Label Content="{Binding Path=[name]}" />`, it does all the magic.

hope this help somebody in the future :)

Comment: You don't need the template in this case at all.

Comment: @svick, yes you are right. adding attribute DisplayMemberPath="[name]" is enough in this case. thank you for pointing this out.