# Binding and displaying a dictionary of dictionaries in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a dictionary of dictionaries I want to display in a data grid.

```
var data = new Dictionary<KeyTypeA, Dictionary<KeyTypeB, string>>();
```

The "inner" dictionaries all share the same keys of a given set of `KeyTypeB`'s which should become the row headers.

The question is related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6236829/1254743), but the difference is that I don't know the keys until runtime.

Comment: Just pack it into a DataTable

Comment: @Frisbee DataTables seam to be primarily intended for WinForms. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253459/how-do-you-create-a-datatable-in-wpf#comment28501654_19253459

Comment: Buy a vowel it is in System.Data.  Yes that was my -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DataGrid` and build a collection of `DataGridColumn` in code as follows (where ColumnCollection is an `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>`):

```
foreach ( string columnName in columns )
{
     ColumnCollection.Add( new DataGridTextColumn()
                           {
                               Header = columnName,
                               Binding = new Binding( String.Format( "[{0}]", columnName ) )
                           } );
}
```

You'll need to figure out how to get the `columns` collection based on you dictionaries and types.

You'll then need to bind the ColumnCollection to your DataGrid columns (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379965/512365) SO answer for that).

Comment: this is roughly the solution I ended with.

Comment: Great. This has worked for me very well. You can even take it further by introducing styles, formatting ... etc. when building the columns in code.

Comment: The only downside is that you need the reference to the control in the view model, which is possible but is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You could define your own type which holds the Header and Binding and create a converter to convert your type to DataGridTextColumns.

Comment: Could you post an example how this would look like?

Comment: I have a collection of DataGridColumns in my VM so I haven't implemented a converter to do this. Basically, you'd define a class w/ various column properties and then create a ValueConverter to convert a collection of those classes to a collection of DataGridColumns.